# What are the meanings of pan(ning) and pan pot?

Tags: terminology

What are the meanings of pan(ning) and pan pot?

from what original meanings of pan and pot are the meanings in sound engineering derived?

Answer (score 7):

*Pot* is short for *potentiometer*, which is a fancy electronics word for "knob" or "dial". *Panning* means positioning something left to right in a stereo sound field. *To pan* is the verb meaning the action of moving something to a certain place in a stereo sound field. So, a *pan pot* is a knob that you turn to move a sound left or right in a stereo mix.

I'm not sure, but I suspect *pan* is short for *panorama* or *panoramic* as in "panoramic sound", which I believe was used to describe stereo sound when it was new and amazing compared to mono sound. Also, *panning* is used in video and filming to mean moving left-to-right or right-to-left while filming, so this is the audio equivalent.

Comment: "Potentiometer" originally meant specifically a variable resistor and I suspect that comes from being able to measure electric potential by adjusting a variable resistance to match a predetermined voltage or current point and using math to calculate the potential based on the resistance. Now "pot" pretty much means any knob; digital, analog, or whatever.

Comment: Potential refers to a voltage.  A potentiometer is a device that acts as a variable voltage divider - proportionally dividing a voltage based on two resistors in series.  In a potentiometer the two resistances are proportion to the position set on the potentiometer so that the output voltage can swing fully between the supply voltage and ground.

Comment: And here I thought the Berlin techno duo Pan-Pot was just choosing extremely common kitchen apparatuses as their name to symbolize the minimalism of their style...